# Problem with font and math environment

Tags: math-mode, fonts, align, brackets

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools} \mathtoolsset{showmanualtags}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}

\begin{document}\sloppy
\begin{align}
y=&A\left[\varTheta_{q}\left[\varTheta_nq_{h,n}^{\frac{\sigma_m-1}{\sigma_m}}+(1-\varTheta_n)q_{h,f}^{\frac{\sigma_m-1}{\sigma_m}}\right]^{\frac{\sigma_m(\sigma_q-1)}{(\sigma_m-1)\sigma_q}}\right.\nonumber\\
&+\left.(1-\varTheta_q)\left[\varTheta_nq_{l,n}^{\frac{\sigma_m-1}{\sigma_m}}+(1-\varTheta_n)q_{l,f}^{\frac{\sigma_m-1}{\sigma_m}}\right]^{\frac{\sigma_m(\sigma_q-1)}{(\sigma_m-1)\sigma_q}}\right]^{\frac{\sigma_q}{\sigma_q-1}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

It worked pretty well, until I've tried to use \left[ ... \right] and the following was showed to me:

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file txexs): Font txexs at 758 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

I figured out that with changing the font from \usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} to

```
\usepackage{mathpazo} 
\usepackage[scale=1.0425]{tgpagella}
\usepackage[scale=.95]{tgheros}
\usepackage{tgcursor}
```

there was no problem anymore, but I want to use the other font. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Runs well for me. What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: MiKTeX with TeXworks.

Comment: @Phteve Have you done the updates?

Comment: @Sebastiano That helped. I just feel a little stupid. Thank You!

Comment: @egreg Thanks too.

Comment: @Phteve Here nobody is little/more/stupid....all the best.